# failed to open stream. no such file or directory Request2.php

Tags: php, http-request2

I am using **Ubuntu 19.10** and have installed `pear/Request2` using `sudo pear install http_request2`. I am trying to use it inside my PHP file while sending a request to **Azure Face API** but it is giving me the following error.

> Warning: require_once(HTTP/Request2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_to_flutter/create_face_list.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'HTTP/Request2.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_to_flutter/create_face_list.php on line 3

I have verified that the required files are available at

> /usr/share/php/HTTP

but it isn't picking them. How am I supposed to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. It might not be an efficient solution but it worked for me. Here are the steps

1. copied **Net** folder to **HTTP** folder
2. copied **HTTP** folder from **/usr/share/php** to my **htdocs** where my .php files were saved.
   Boom!!! It worked perfectly fine. 
   If anyone has any other solution, please share it. I'll try that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As official PEAR manual states, before requiring the packages files you should check if the directory where pear stores all its extensions added to "include_path" .ini php settings, and if it's not you should add it manually.
[Official documentation](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php)

But you better switch from pear to composer as pear already dead package manager that is not updating for long term

Comment: I'll check the composer. For now, It's working fine. I hope it'll work too when I'll upload my database online and the PHP files too.  Thanks for that. I'll check out your method too